# Create a BAT file to run multiple file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

i need to create a BAT file to run multiple file.File are in the same folder but they have different name and have different parameter.
There are some example of file:

```
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_2_02_02_1.csv 7
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_2_02_02_2.csv 7
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_2_02_02_3.csv 7
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_2_02_02_4.csv 7
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_2_02_04_1.csv 7
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_2_02_04_2.csv 7
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_2_02_04_3.csv 7
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_2_02_04_4.csv 7
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_2_02_06_1.csv 7
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_2_02_06_2.csv 7
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_2_02_06_3.csv 7
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_2_02_06_4.csv 7
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_2_02_08_1.csv 7
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_3_08_02_3.csv 10
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_3_08_02_4.csv 10
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_3_08_04_1.csv 10
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_3_08_04_2.csv 10
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_3_08_04_3.csv 10
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_3_08_04_4.csv 10
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_3_08_06_1.csv 10
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_3_08_06_2.csv 10
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_3_08_06_3.csv 10
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_3_08_06_4.csv 10
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_3_08_08_1.csv 10
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_30_3_08_08_2.csv 10
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_50_2_06_08_1.csv 12
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_50_2_06_08_2.csv 12
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_50_2_06_08_3.csv 12
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_50_2_06_08_4.csv 12
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_50_2_06_10_1.csv 12
.\MMDSv1.0.exe I_50_2_06_10_2.csv 12
```

Someone can help me? Thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have shown a list of example file names, but you did not *explained* how the file names must be processed, so I got my old crystal ball, cleaned it and asked it: "what this problem is about?" and this was the answer:

*"Giving a list of file names comprised of several parts separated by underscore and a list of numbers, select a different number as parameter each time that a new file name differs from the previous one in the first three parts"*.

So this is the solution:

**EDIT**: After the OP had finally gave us the right method, this is the correct solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1-3* delims=_" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D *.csv') do (
   set /A number=%%b*%%c*12/100
   MMDSv1.0.exe %%a_%%b_%%c_%%d !number!
)
```

Comment: there arent a specific order to process the file, it is only important that every file have the correct number associated,

Comment: Perfect! How the "correct number" is associated to each file? As I said before, we are NOT mind readers! Do you want to solve your problem or play guessing games?

Comment: i calculate the number in this mode : n*m*0.12 where n is the first number after I_ and m is the second number. For example 7 is calculate by 0.12*30*2

Comment: See the edit in my answer... How easy is to solve a problem when the specifications are complete! Isn't it? (I need to do a small adjustment in my crystal ball)

Comment: Thanks a lot Aacini! if i want execute every file 5 times, how can i do that? i want execute 5 times first file, after that 5 times second file...

Comment: Well, if this answer already aids you, you should select its check-mark before you post any _additional_ request...

Comment: If you want to execute each file 5 times, use this: `for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do MMDSv1.0.exe %%a_%%b_%%c_%%d !number!`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! Another question is if i have to create another batch that does this : .\SolutionVerifier.exe I_30_2_02_02_1.csv I_30_2_02_02_1_sol.csv
.\SolutionVerifier.exe I_30_2_02_02_2.csv I_30_2_02_02_2_sol.csv ecc for all files?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what is the logic behind the numbers passed last so I've put them in the iterations list too:

```
@echo off
for %%# in (

    "I_30_2_02_02_1.csv 7"
    "I_30_2_02_02_2.csv 7"
    "I_30_2_02_02_3.csv 7"
    "I_30_2_02_02_4.csv 7"
    "I_30_2_02_04_1.csv 7"
    "I_30_2_02_04_2.csv 7"
    "I_30_2_02_04_3.csv 7"
    "I_30_2_02_04_4.csv 7"
    "I_30_2_02_06_1.csv 7"
    "I_30_2_02_06_2.csv 7"
    "I_30_2_02_06_3.csv 7"
    "I_30_2_02_06_4.csv 7"
    "I_30_2_02_08_1.csv 7"
    "I_30_3_08_02_3.csv 10"
    "I_30_3_08_02_4.csv 10"
    "I_30_3_08_04_1.csv 10"
    "I_30_3_08_04_2.csv 10"
    "I_30_3_08_04_3.csv 10"
    "I_30_3_08_04_4.csv 10"
    "I_30_3_08_06_1.csv 10"
    "I_30_3_08_06_2.csv 10"
    "I_30_3_08_06_3.csv 10"
    "I_30_3_08_06_4.csv 10"
    "I_30_3_08_08_1.csv 10"
    "I_30_3_08_08_2.csv 10"
    "I_50_2_06_08_1.csv 12"
    "I_50_2_06_08_2.csv 12"
    "I_50_2_06_08_3.csv 12"
    "I_50_2_06_08_4.csv 12"
    "I_50_2_06_10_1.csv 12"
    "I_50_2_06_10_2.csv 12"
) do (

    .\MMDSv1.0.exe %%~#

)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have a lot of file , i think a solution like "I_30_2_02_*.csv 7" ,  i try to create a general line for all file that have the same parameter, it is possible?

Comment: @user3836982 you can use wild cards in the FOR loop but the numbers passed at the end will be a problem.If you know when `7`,`10` or `12` should be used you can use nested loops which will save you a lot of writing.

Comment: Yes i konw when 7,10 12 are use but i am not able to create a bat file that can do that

Comment: If you know when the 7, 10 and 12 are used, why you didn't explained that to us? We are _not_ mind readers... **`:(`**

Answer (score 0):

As there is no predictable pattern for the parameters, generating this from a formula looks to be unreliable.

You can build a text file with all the possible parameters sets and just loop through it. For simplicity, make sure that the text file and batch file are in a folder that has no spaces in the path or file name or this command will fail.

The Text File called "Commands.txt" in same folder as batch file:

```
I_30_2_02_02_1.csv 7
I_30_2_02_02_2.csv 7
I_30_2_02_02_3.csv 7
I_30_2_02_02_4.csv 7
I_30_2_02_04_1.csv 7
I_30_2_02_04_2.csv 7
I_30_2_02_04_3.csv 7
I_30_2_02_04_4.csv 7
I_30_2_02_06_1.csv 7
I_30_2_02_06_2.csv 7
I_30_2_02_06_3.csv 7
I_30_2_02_06_4.csv 7
I_30_2_02_08_1.csv 7
I_30_3_08_02_3.csv 10
I_30_3_08_02_4.csv 10
I_30_3_08_04_1.csv 10
I_30_3_08_04_2.csv 10
I_30_3_08_04_3.csv 10
I_30_3_08_04_4.csv 10
I_30_3_08_06_1.csv 10
I_30_3_08_06_2.csv 10
I_30_3_08_06_3.csv 10
I_30_3_08_06_4.csv 10
I_30_3_08_08_1.csv 10
I_30_3_08_08_2.csv 10
I_50_2_06_08_1.csv 12
I_50_2_06_08_2.csv 12
I_50_2_06_08_3.csv 12
I_50_2_06_08_4.csv 12
I_50_2_06_10_1.csv 12
I_50_2_06_10_2.csv 12
```

Then in your batch file put the following:

```
FOR /F %%F IN (%~dp0Commands.txt) DO (
    %~dp0MMDSv1.0.exe %%~F
)
```

If there are spaces in the path or file use this alternate command:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* " %%F IN (`echo "%~dp0Commands.txt"') DO (
    %~dp0MMDSv1.0.exe %%~F
)
```

The single quote charactors are the back quote which is on the same key as the ~, and the double quotes are the standard quote charactor used in batch files and may be altered by some browsers.